# How to mock a named nestjs Logger with ts-mockito

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs, ts-mockito

Our project uses nestjs with mocha, chai and ts-mockito for testing and I can't figure out how to test a named nestjs `Logger`.

`new Logger()` can be tested as expected:

```
describe('basic test', () => {
    it('works', async () => {
        const mockLogger = mock<LoggerService>();
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: TestClass,
                    useValue: new TestClass(),
                },
            ],
        })
            .setLogger(instance(mockLogger))
            .compile();

        const unit = moduleRef.get(TestClass);

        unit.log();

        verify(mockLogger.error(anything())).once();
    });
});

class TestClass {
    readonly logger: Logger;
    constructor() {
        this.logger = new Logger();
    }

    public log() {
        this.logger.error(new Error());
    }
}
```

but using a named logger fails the test:

```
class TestClass {
    readonly logger: Logger;
    constructor() {
        this.logger = new Logger('name');
    }

    public log() {
        this.logger.error(new Error());
    }
}
```

with `// Expected "error(anything())" to be called 1 time(s). But has been called 0 time(s).`

Comment: note this is a ts-mockito problem - doing the same thing with jest works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the optional parameter issue by using `capture` instead of `verify` e.g. before:

```
    verify(mockX.getUsers({key: 'val'}) ).once();
```

after:

```
    const [opts] = capture(mockX.getUsers).last();
    expect(opts).toEqual({key: 'val'});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way ts-mockito handles optional function arguments. A question on this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72799374/1515209)

Calling

```
new Logger('name').error(message);
```

is effectively the same as calling

```
new Logger().error('message', 'name');
```

and the mock needs to be changed to reflect this difference in arguments.

Changing

```
verify(mockLogger.error(anything())).once();
```

to

```
verify(mockLogger.error(anything(), anything())).once();
```

fixes the problem.